# PyQt, importar clase correctamente

Tags: python, mongodb, pyqt

De nuevo me he quedado pillado,en mi lento progreso con PyQt. Ahora estoy con otro ejemplo de conexion con bbdd. El ejemplo es sencillo una QDialog, en el cual tengo un boton y al pulsarlo inserta un registro en una bbdd Mongodb. El programa lo tengo dividido en el main y otro el cual tiene el metodo de la bbdd. No termino de pillar lo de importar las clases desde otro archivo

main.py

```
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import QDialog, QMessageBox
from PyQt5 import uic
#si el archivo bbdd es en el mismo directorio que main
import bbdd
#si el archivo bbdd esta en una carpeta hija llamada bbdd dentro 
from bbdd import bbdd

class ventana(QDialog):
    def __init__(self):
        QDialog.__init__(self)
        uic.loadUi('ui.ui')

        self.boton.clicked.connect(self.Accion)

    def Accion(self):
        ¿¿¿¿¿¿¿¿¿?????????
```

bbdd.py

```
from pymongo import MongoClient
class bbdd():
    def ficha(self):
        self.serverdb = self.MongoClient('10.10.10.10', 27017)
        self.db = self.serverdb.ERP
        self.coleccion = self.db.Tabla
        self.coleccion.insert({'_id':22,'Nombre':'pepe', 'años':20})
        self.serverdb.close()
```

Donde pongo:

```
¿¿¿¿¿¿¿¿¿?????????
```

pongo:

```
self.serverdb = MongoClient('10.10.10.10', 27017)
self.bd = self.serverdb.ERP
self.coleccion = self.bd.Fichas
self.coleccion.insert({'_id': 22, 'Nombre': 'pepe', 'años': 20})
self.serverdb.close()
```

Funciona perfectamente. La cuestion de poner el metodo de la bbdd, aparte es porque tengo pensado en el programa crear otros metodos que se conectaran a diferentes bbdd y colecciones(tablas). ¿porque he elegido Mongodb? Por hacer algo diferente.

Me podéis explicar de que manera lo tengo que importar.

Comment: Donde estan los: ????? debes colocar solo bbdd().ficha()

Comment: `bbdd.bbdd().ficha()` si usas `import bbdd` y `bbdd().ficha()` si usas `from bbdd import bbdd`.

Comment: Gracias, por contestar @FJSevilla. Lo he testeado y tanto, si uso import , como form import, las 2 funcionan con bbdd.bbdd().ficha() [archivo.clase().metodo()]. Con from import no funciona bbdd().ficha() [archivo().metodo()] me devuelve error TypeError: 'module' object is not callable

Comment: Gracias a ti tambien @eyllanesc